# Can American mother living in France bring French father with her to the US right now?

Tags: covid-19

I live in the US. My parents want to come and visit me. My mother now has dual citizenship France/US (born and raised in US, moved to France later). My father is only French.

My mother believes right now that she's not even allowed by herself back to the US because she lives in France. It sounds crazy to me, but is it true?

I know France right now would allow the reverse situation (French citizen allowed to bring US spouse to France just on the basis of their being married), but I'm not sure whether the other way around (title question) is true.

If you don't know, do you have any idea where I could call and find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the US side of things, per the relevant [Presidential proclamation](https://trumpwhitehouse.archives.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-2019-novel-coronavirus/), the ban:

- does not apply to US citizens, regardless of their place of residence.
- exempts spouses of US citizens, regardless of their place of residence.

However:

- You may want to check if there are any state-level restrictions (I don't think there are any) or quarantine requirements
- They will need to get a test before their flight
- Your father needs an ESTA or visa
- Your father will need to have some proof of their marriage

**However** on the french side of things, you are apparently currently still not allowed to leave the country without an "imperious motive", and "visiting your child" isn't one.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I think you missed the fact that the father is married to a US citizen, so Section 2(a)(ii) applies, not 2(a)(iii).

Comment: The ESTA will likely be cancelled.  See https://fr.usembassy.gov/visas/covid-19-visa-esta-faq/  The statement there is incomplete, because it overlooks spouses of US citizens, but at least one person here has reported such a cancellation despite being the spouse of a US citizen.

Comment: You are exactly right, thanks. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can only accept and not upvote as a guest sorry. As for the last part, are you saying that France is preventing its own citizens from leaving the country? Do you have a link to that current law by any chance?

Comment: Also is it possible that these laws have changed. I see that the proclamation is from when Trump was president. Does it still hold now?

Comment: @georgeusfrance The current rules for travelling from/to France are [here](https://www.interieur.gouv.fr/Actualites/L-actu-du-Ministere/Certificate-of-international-travel).

Comment: @georgeusfrance The proclamation has been renewed as is, as far as I know. The only change I know of at the federal level is the added requirement to get tested before the flight.

Comment: @georgeusfrance Note that your mother could use the "Return to the country of residence or origin" exception to leave France, using her US citizenship for that. But that would most likely not apply to your father. As far as I know, enforcement is spotty, but those are the current rules.

Answer (score -1):

According to https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/presidential-proclamation-coronavirus.html, US citizens and their spouses (as well as members of various other categories of people) are not subject to the covid-related bans on travel.